# How to access package variable from function?

Tags: r, scope

How can I access a package variable from a function in the same package?

The following code only changes `x` locally to the function. How can I change `myPackage::x` from that function?

Example:

```
x <- list()
populate_list <- function() {
    x["a"] <- 4
}
```

--

Here is the full code I'm using to test this with `get`. The `cache` key is simply chosen to be different every time the package is run. This is the package code, in `R/get_obj.R`

```
cache <- list()
test_cache <- function(){
    cache <- get("cache")
    cache[[paste(sample.int(10),collapse="-")]] <- 1
    return(cache)
}
```

I test it in R with:

```
> library(devtools)
> load_all("mypackage")
Loading mypackage
> mypackage::test_cache()
$`4-1-6-5-9-3-10-2-7-8`
[1] 1

> mypackage::test_cache()
$`6-9-7-10-5-1-4-2-3-8`
[1] 1

> mypackage::cache
list()
```

For `mypackage::cache` and the second run of `mypackage::test_cache()`, I expected this list as output:

```
$`4-1-6-5-9-3-10-2-7-8`
[1] 1

$`6-9-7-10-5-1-4-2-3-8`
[1] 1
```

Comment: Try making `cache` an environment - you're running into R's default copy-on-modify behaviour.

Comment: You are also defining a local variable called cache inside of the test_cache function. What happens if you remove the line `cache <-get("cache")` but leave the rest the same? You may still need to use an environment for cache since the change inside of the method will cause the value to be copied as suggested above.

Comment: @RobGevers Similar to what's in the first example? Then the variable is not modified in the "package" scope.

Comment: It seems like you are mixing the package scope and the function scope. If the cache line is outside of the scope of the package and you want to create the variable and then have those functions use it you will need to pass an environment around as suggested by @Hadley and then use the get methods I pointed you to in my answer to tell it that the environment is the one you want the variable to be scoped in.

Comment: @RobGevers Sorry, I'm new to environments and don't quite understand. Yes, I want to access the package scope from the function scope. A static for only that function would also work. If I created an environment with `cache` and passed that environment around, couldn't I just as well pass `cache' around from the start?

Comment: @RobGevers I've solved it and posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<<-` operator searches the parent environments for an existing definition, so the following gives me what I wanted:

```
x <- list()
populate_list <- function() {
    x["a"] <<- 4
}
```

Or for the other example:

```
cache <- list()
test_cache <- function(){
    cache[[paste(sample.int(10),collapse="-")]] <<- 1
    return(cache)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [get method](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html). It allows you to pull variables directly from specific environments rather than relying on the lexical scoping of the current method.

The documentation for [environments](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/environment.html) should help make this argument for get more clear though it is difficult to identify the exact syntax without knowing the scenario.

In general it is not a good idea to hide variables by defining them at a local scope if you know you will want to access them more globally.

Comment: Which environment should I supply? `x <- get("x")` doesn't throw an error but doesn't seem to find the right variable, either.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about defining variables at a local scope. How do you suggest I solve the problem instead? I need a "package global" that can be modified from a function in the package. The variable is used to cache some expensive operations done in the function.

Comment: If you are working on this problem as the package writer, you should be able to define the function and use it anywhere you need to as long as you do not define something else using the same variable name. Can you update your question with a more thorough example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I've updated the question with a more thorough example of what happens and what I want to happen.